# Replace '-' but not negative numbers in pandas

Tags: pandas, replace

In a DataFrame, I have negative numbers, and also missing values that are given by a `-` .  I want to replace the missing values with an empty cell, but this operation should NOT remove the `-` in front of the negative numbers.

It looks like:

```
45      45      45      45      45      45      45      45      45      45
45      45      15      31      43      45      45      45      45      45
44.24   121.55  1.80    0.00%   -       97.63   -4.87   -6.02   -20.14  169.19
1       1       7       12      3       1       1       1       1       1
```

So the missing value cell with the `-` should be empty, but the `-4.87` should stay intact.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you planning on parsing the 0.00%? Is this a CSV you're reading from? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

The problem should have been addressed at the time of loading the file into the DataFrame (by providing the `na_values` parameter to `read_csv()` or whatever function you used).

At this point, use operation `replace()`: it replaces whole words, not individual characters.

```
df = df.replace("-", np.nan)
```